# How to check member in merkle tree

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries

[image]

If we want to check that data is member of it or not we will take the root, data block, and all the blocks in path between data and root. According to this picture if i want to check that data block, then how can i validate the hash pointer store in above block without having left child?

Answer (score -1):

this is the picture of proof path, if you want to get the path, technically you need calculate the hash of all the data block and get the whole merkle tree